# How to avoid commit for mybatis sql session in a multi-thread context

Tags: java, database, mybatis

I have a restful service which use mybatis for the persistence layer. I use SqlSessionTemplate. Now for test, I start the war in a embedded tomcat in Maven and then share the context with my tests. So they can use the same db connection. I was hoping the tests can be done in transactions. For each test scenario, data get setup at beginning and rollback after the test. Meanwhile, I used SingleConnectionDataSource for datasource, so all the session will share the same db connection.

But I found since the restful service is multi-thread. It turns out every session will in a thread, so the SqlSession need to be closed, so the session forced commit on the connection. Just wondering how can i avoid the commit?

```
SqlSession sqlSession = getSqlSession(
      SqlSessionTemplate.this.sqlSessionFactory,
      SqlSessionTemplate.this.executorType,
      SqlSessionTemplate.this.exceptionTranslator);
  try {
    Object result = method.invoke(sqlSession, args);
    if (!isSqlSessionTransactional(sqlSession, SqlSessionTemplate.this.sqlSessionFactory)) {
      // force commit even on non-dirty sessions because some databases require
      // a commit/rollback before calling close()
      sqlSession.commit(true);
    }
    return result;
```

Here is the code of SqlSessionInterceptor, you can see it checks isSqlSessionTransactional(), then it force sqlSession to commit.